# A number that is a word

Tags: cipher, password

Below I have a string of numbers, these numbers form to become words and letters. It's your job to find out what the phrase is.

> 10-0-12-15-16-24-0-21-9-6-0-2-15-20-24-6-19

Good luck with deciphering the code.

Comment: Please see [Code Puzzles: What (Not) To Do?](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/1717/5373) on meta.

Comment: Is it a phrase, set of words or just a word? In the body you say it's a phrase, but you tagged the question [tag:word].

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The phrase is:

> I KNOW THE ANSWER

Each number ...

> .. corresponds to one letter or a space. A zero means space, any other number *n* corresponds to the letter at position (*n* − 1) in the alphabet. The first letter is the 9th letter in the alphabet, I. An A is encoded as 2.